# Enable SSL in ActiveMQ - connection getting timed out while accessing web console over https

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic

I have a RHEL 7 server where I have ActiveMQ installed (version : `apache-activemq-5.15.11`).I am trying to run the web console over https and hence I went through the instructions mentioned in the documentation [here](https://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html) and made changes in my `jetty.xml` and un-commented the following section:

```
                 <!--
                    Enable this connector if you wish to use https with web console
                -->
                <!-- bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                    <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
                        
                            <property name="keyStorePath" value="${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" />
                            <property name="keyStorePassword" value="password" />
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="port" value="8162" />
                </bean -->
```

when I am trying to access the web console like the following:

`https://myserver.com:8162/admin/index.jsp`

I am getting connection getting timed out in the browser.

Questions :

1. Am I trying to access it properly - via port `8162`? It works fine with port `8161` and over `http` like the following:

`http://myserver.com:8161/admin/index.jsp`

2. Are there any additional changes needed to make it work over https?

My `jetty.xml` is below for reference:

```
 <!--
        Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor
        license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional
        information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to You under
        the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in
        compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at

        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by applicable law or
        agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an
        "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
        implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
        limitations under the License.
    -->
    <!--
        An embedded servlet engine for serving up the Admin consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and
        some demos Include this file in your configuration to enable ActiveMQ web components
        e.g. <import resource="jetty.xml"/>
    -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="securityLoginService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
        <property name="name" value="ActiveMQRealm" />
        <property name="config" value="${activemq.conf}/jetty-realm.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
        <property name="roles" value="user,admin" />
        <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
        <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="adminSecurityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
        <property name="roles" value="admin" />
         <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
        <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="securityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
        <property name="constraint" ref="securityConstraint" />
        <property name="pathSpec" value="/api/*,/admin/*,*.jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="adminSecurityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
        <property name="constraint" ref="adminSecurityConstraint" />
        <property name="pathSpec" value="*.action" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="rewriteHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
        <property name="rules">
            <list>
                <bean id="header" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                  <property name="pattern" value="*"/>
                  <property name="name" value="X-FRAME-OPTIONS"/>
                  <property name="value" value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
                </bean>
                <bean id="header" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                  <property name="pattern" value="*"/>
                  <property name="name" value="X-XSS-Protection"/>
                  <property name="value" value="1; mode=block"/>
                </bean>
                <bean id="header" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                  <property name="pattern" value="*"/>
                  <property name="name" value="X-Content-Type-Options"/>
                  <property name="value" value="nosniff"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="secHandlerCollection" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <property name="handlers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="rewriteHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                    <property name="contextPath" value="/admin" />
                    <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" />
                    <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                    <property name="contextPath" value="/api" />
                    <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/api" />
                    <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
                    <property name="directoriesListed" value="false" />
                    <property name="welcomeFiles">
                        <list>
                            <value>index.html</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                    <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/" />
                </bean>
                <bean id="defaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler">
                    <property name="serveIcon" value="false" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
        <property name="loginService" ref="securityLoginService" />
        <property name="authenticator">
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator" />
        </property>
        <property name="constraintMappings">
            <list>
                <ref bean="adminSecurityConstraintMapping" />
                <ref bean="securityConstraintMapping" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="handler" ref="secHandlerCollection" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
    </bean>

    <bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
             <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
        <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
        <property name="port" value="8161"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="Server" depends-on="jettyPort" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server"
        destroy-method="stop">

        <property name="handler">
            <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
                <property name="handlers">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="contexts" />
                        <ref bean="securityHandler" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="invokeConnectors" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="Server" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setConnectors" />
        <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
                    <!-- see the jettyPort bean -->
                   <property name="host" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.host']}" />
                   <property name="port" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.port']}" />
               </bean>
                <!--
                    Enable this connector if you wish to use https with web console
                -->
                <!-- Enabling the following connector on Nov 11,2020 for HTTPS  -->

                <bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                    <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
                        
                            <property name="keyStorePath" value="${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" />
                            <property name="keyStorePassword" value="password" />
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="port" value="8162" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="configureJetty" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticMethod" value="org.apache.activemq.web.config.JspConfigurer.configureJetty" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <ref bean="Server" />
                <ref bean="secHandlerCollection" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="invokeStart" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" 
        depends-on="configureJetty, invokeConnectors">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="Server" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="start" />      
    </bean>
    
    
</beans>
```